# How to hide a navigation bar from first ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I hide a navigation bar from first ViewController or a particular ViewController in swift?

I used the following code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

and also on `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Both methods hide the navigation controller from all ViewControllers.

Comment: you need to manage it manually for all viewcontrollers.. you can't do it for any one..

Answer (score 522, accepted):

If you know that all other views should have the bar visible, you could use `viewWillDisappear` to set it to visible again.

In Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: This answer is more efficient . Think of the repetitive code with each new ViewController you add. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39679506/5079380

Answer (score 268):

Swift 3

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: With overriding don't forget to call the super methods: super.viewWillAppear(animated) and super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

Comment: Does it remove the link that says back?

Comment: I was convinced that it would not work well with the "swipe back" on the visual level, but everything is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: `self.` not needed.

Comment: On the swipe back, from the view with the navigation bar to the view with the hidden navigation bar, how do we reimplement the navigation bar fading?

Comment: When I present modal on it from the bottom, the animation is showing the navigation bar with animation, and it's looks bad...

Answer (score 80):

You can unhide `navigationController` in `viewWillDisappear`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 27):

You could also create an extension for this so you will be able to reuse the extension without implementing this again and again in every view controller.

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func hideNavigationBar(animated: Bool){
        // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)

    }

    func showNavigationBar(animated: Bool) {
        // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

So you can use the extension methods as below

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        hideNavigationBar(animated: animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        showNavigationBar(animated: animated)
    }
```

Comment: Not really worth the extension, is it? :)

Comment: Depends on how many views you are hiding/showing the nav bars. I feel like most cases you only hide the first one but if you do it a lot the extension is nice.

Comment: Definitely, it doesn't worth it. Don't invent something already exists.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3,  you can use isNavigationBarHidden Property also to show or hide navigation bar

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide the navigation bar for current view controller
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
   self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ways to hide Navigation Bar in Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) worked for me

Answer (score 5):

#### Want to Hide the NavigationBar on the First ViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

#### Want to Show the NavigationBar on the Second ViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Best simplest solution!

Answer (score 3):

Ways to show Navigation Bar in Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Answer (score 3):

```
     private func setupView() {
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        }
```

Alternative

in viewDidLoad use this settings

```
title = "Madman"
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Check the constraints of Collectionview, scrollview or tableView

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /*.  Swift 5  */     
    let controller =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sc_userNavigation") as! UserNavigationViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

> In IOS 8 do it like

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

but only when it's part of a **UINavigationController**

make it false when you want it back

Answer (score 0):

I use a variant of the above, and isolate sections of my app to be embedded in differing NavControllers. This way, i don't have to reset visibility. Very useful in startup sequences, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Call the set hide method in view Will appear and Disappear. if you will not call the method in view will disappear with status false.It will hide the navigation bar in complete navigation hierarchy

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: This is a copy/paste response. What is the difference between your response and the other 2 or 3 equal responses here??

Answer (score -3):

You can do it from the window controller (Swift3)

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the Window Controller ?

Comment: This is for macOS, not iOS