# removing the navigation title bar on the first view

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

[image]

hey guys Im using navigation controller but what I want to do is remove the huge space made by navigation controller on the first view but retain the back button on the succeeding views. TIA

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209453/how-to-hide-a-navigation-bar-from-first-viewcontroller-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) 
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   self.navigationController?.idNavigationBarHidden = false;
}
```