# How to make a navigation bar extend an image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9, swift4

**Issue:**

I have a navigation controller embedded. For a particular view controller, I want an image to be extended on the nav bar, which upon scrolling should scroll as well. What would be the best way to go about with this. I kind of assume that for this particular view controller I would have to remove nav bar, but how do I do that?

**Pls refer below Image.**

[image]

Comment: Before asking, First search on google. If condition does not matched then mentioned your tried code or links that you already gone through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a navigation bar from first ViewController in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209453/how-to-hide-a-navigation-bar-from-first-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: if your question is about how to hide the nav bar then the answer is - call setNavigationBarHidden method from within the view controller.