# Do I have to use NavigationController in my coordinators code?

Tags: swift4, coordinator-pattern, transition-coordinator

I am refactoring my codes and want to give Coordinators a try.

However, I am not quite comfortable with `UINavigationController` in charge, cause it creates a Back button on child coordinates as well as an unwanted top bar which I don’t want.

Is there anyway I could use ordinary `UIViewController` instead of `UINavigationController`?

P.S : it is a sample code I found [Here][1]

protocol Coordinator {
    func start()
}

protocol FlowACoordinatable {
    var coordinator: FlowACoordinator
}

class FlowACoordinator: Coordinator {

```
private var navigationController: UINavigationController

private var firstVC: FirstViewController
private var secondVC: SecondViewController

init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    self.navigationController = navigationController
}

func start() { ... }

func present(_ viewController: (FlowACoordinatable & UIViewController)) {
    viewController.coordinator = self
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}

...
```

}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, FlowACoordinatable {

```
var coordinator: FlowACoordinator?

func buttonTapped() {
    self.coordinator?.goToNextStep()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Coordinators architecture is based on `UINavigationController` and **can not** be replaced by `UIViewController`.

But still, it is possible to hide the buttom bar pane using *Object Inspection* and check *Hide buttom bar...* or do it [by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209453/how-to-hide-a-navigation-bar-from-first-viewcontroller-in-swift).