# Swift NavigationControllerBar Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, view, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am new in iOS development and in Swift. I have a question. I added in one of the ViewController NavigationController. But I have some problems with back button cause it doesn't appear on other Views. I tried with `self.pushViewController()` and with `self.present()` but it doesn't work. If I mark in NavigationController `Is Initial View Controller` then everything is fine but I don't want it because then app starts with this screen(where I have NavigationController).

Please help me, what I should to add or to write?

This is an image of my storyboard
[image: This is an image of my storyboard]

And this is what I have if I run and go to another ViewController, as you can see I don't have navigation bar and back button.
[image]

Comment: You should embed your navigation controller to the first viewcontroller and hide the navigation bar then show it for the rest. check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209623/4569257

Comment: @OmarChaabouni I override only viewWillAppear() to the first viewcontroller should I add there viewWillDisapper() or I add this function in the second one(i override viewWillDisappear only in the second viewcontroller)?

Comment: Both work but I would do it in the viewWillDisappear

Comment: "If I mark in NavigationController Is Initial View Controller then everything is fine but I don't want it because then app starts with this screen(where I have NavigationController)" But that is excellent! Explain how you get beyond the initial screen that the app starts with.

Comment: @OmarChaabouni I did it but still same, nothing happened. By the way, I deleted this part and in general, it must me show navigation bar(i mean in the first viewcontroller) but I didn't get it

Comment: @matt if I understand you correctly, now I have another one screen where I can log out from app

Comment: @Lado did you embed your initial viewcontroller with a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

You got 2 options :

1) Add a navigation controller in the root ViewController, Hide throughout except the last one. Make sure you push the last VC so Back option will be there by default

```
self.navigationController.pushToViewController(BarCodeViewController)
```

2) Use a custom View on top of last viewController add a custom button to that view. But this time present it from previous ViewController

```
self.present(BarCodeViewController)
```

when back button clicked dismiss it by adding target to the button. `self.dismiss()`