# Navigation Bar hide is not working in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having Three Views. I want to hide the navigation bar in the third View. Even if I give `.navigationBarHidden(true)` the navigation bar is displaying!

I couldn't find where I'm doing wrong. I've attached my code and the resulting screenshot below.

Xcode version - 11.1

```
struct ContentViewOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                
                Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("View One")
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewTwo()) {
                        Text("Navigate to View Two")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("View One")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("View Two")
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewThree()) {
                    Text("Navigate to View Three")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("View Two")
    }
}

struct ContentViewThree: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("View Three")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("View Three")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209453/how-to-hide-a-navigation-bar-from-first-viewcontroller-in-swift

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**NOTE:** (For some reason it works in some cases) `SwiftUI` requires that you need to `.navigationBarTitle` for `.navigationBarHidden` to work properly.

```
NavigationView {
    ScrollView() {
     ......
    }.  
    .navigationBarTitle("") //this must be empty
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
```

Comment: When adding `.navigationBarTitle("")` in a view inside a TabBar, the label of that Tab is being erased upon selecting it. What I did is to set the label of the tab again instead of ""

Comment: This is mindless, besides it needs to be added in each view of the navigation.

Comment: if you put NavigationView and you want to hide it. you have to write code for hidden. its bug of SwiftUI

Comment: and also getting a warning: "changing items while animating can result in a corrupted navigation bar"

Comment: Adding `.navigationBarHidden` to ScrollView worked for my case.

Comment: Not working in iOS 15

Comment: @TanvirgeekLet me check and update

Comment: Not working in iOS 16.3

Answer (score 6):

I tried multiple solutions, including UINavigationControllerDelegate and nothing seems to make the navigationBar permanently hidden. Until I tried KVO :)

So if you want a permanent solution, use this:

```
struct NoBarNavigationView<Content: View>: View {

    private let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content
                .introspectNavigationController { (UINavigationController) in
                    NavigationControllerDelegate.shared.becomeDelegate(of: UINavigationController)
                }
        }
    }
}

class NavigationControllerDelegate: NSObject {

    static let shared = NavigationControllerDelegate()

    func becomeDelegate(of navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navigationController.navigationBar.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "alpha", options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        // This is necessary to ensure the UINavigationBar remains hidden
        if let navigationBar = object as? UINavigationBar {
            navigationBar.isHidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

Happy coding!

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, I am using:

```
import Introspect
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

Comment: You should probably show the `import Introspect` and [link](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to the GitHub.

Comment: Nothing else worked consistently for me. Thanks!

Comment: wow thats something that i've been looking for so long and that was the only thing that worked for me so far! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Posting this for more visibility in dealing with SwiftUI NavigationBar not hiding, or still taking up space when it is hidden:

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
```

That sets a title (hack sometimes required for old swiftUI versions), hides the bar, but also tells the rendering engine to ignore any safe areas that reserve space for the navigation bar (presumptively).

Comment: Line `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)` alone did the trick for me.
It is important to set it after `.navigationBarHidden(true)`

Comment: This was a solution for me. I don't even have a navigation view.

Answer (score 3):

With iOS 15.5 and 15.6 `.navigationBarHidden(true)` simply doesn't work. Adding `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)` doesn't help either. It's obviously a bug in iOS 15.

**It's fixed in iOS 16!**

Tested with Xcode 14 Simulated iOS 15.5, iPhone w/ iOS 15.6 and iOS 16 on an iPhone X, the bug got fixed in iOS 16.

Answer (score 2):

To hide the `NavigationBar` specifically in your 3rd `View`. You have to remove `.navigationBarTitle("View Three")` and the bar gets hidden:

```
struct ContentViewThree: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("View Three")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .navigationBarHidden(true) on navigationView, or if you have NavigationLink you need to add on the Link

```
   NavigationLink("",
                               destination: Text("TEST"),
                               tag: linkValue,
                               selection: $linksNavigator.selection)
                    **.navigationBarHidden(true)**
```

Comment: wow, this is such a strange behaviour, to have to set navigatoinbarHidden for all the navigation links you have on the page as well

Comment: I've found this also hides the navigation bar on the view holding the navigation link (possibly this is how it works as the child view inherits the status of the parent?)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Because you should add hidden properties to DetailView instead of NavigationLink,

```
 NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(mData: sportData)
                                .navigationBarTitle("")
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                
                ) {
                    Image("arrowRight3").resizable()
                    //.padding(5)
                    //.background(.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15 you can use a @State property to toggle the state.

```
@State private var hideNavigationbar: Bool = false
```

You switching the value in **.onAppear {}** to true. When you dismiss the view you call **.onDisappear {}** and set the property to false.

Now you can use it like so:

```
.navigationbarHidden(hideNavigationbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The latest hiding method, suitable for iOS15**

```swift
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.ignoresSafeArea()
```