# How can I remove an element of main.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

How do I remove the "Wrapper" element and buttons "back" and "menu" from main.storyboard? but to keep loading bar
I tried to delete part of the code but it gives errors.

I will be very happy if someone helps me. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Below you will find the code I use

ViewController.swift:

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var offlineView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var offlineIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var offlineButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    // MARK: Globals
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var tempView: WKWebView!
    var progressBar : UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.title = appTitle
        setupApp()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    // UI Actions
    // handle back press
    @IBAction func onLeftButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if (webView.canGoBack) {
            webView.goBack()
            // fix a glitch, as the above seems to trigger observeValue -> WKWebView.isLoading
            activityIndicatorView.isHidden = true
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        } else {
            // exit app
            UIControl().sendAction(#selector(URLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
        }
    }
    // open menu in page, or fire alternate function on large screens
    @IBAction func onRightButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if (changeMenuButtonOnWideScreens && isWideScreen()) {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(alternateRightButtonJavascript, completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(menuButtonJavascript, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    // reload page from offline screen
    @IBAction func onOfflineButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        offlineView.isHidden = true
        webViewContainer.isHidden = false
        loadAppUrl()
    }
    
    // Observers for updating UI
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if (keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading)) {
            // show activity indicator

            /*
            // this causes troubles when swiping back and forward.
            // having this disabled means that the activity view is only shown on the startup of the app.
            // ...which is fair enough.
            if (webView.isLoading) {
                activityIndicatorView.isHidden = false
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            }
            */
        }
        if (keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress)) {
            progressBar.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)
            rightButton.isEnabled = (webView.estimatedProgress == 1)
        }
    }
    
    // Initialize WKWebView
    func setupWebView() {
        // set up webview
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webViewContainer.frame.width, height: webViewContainer.frame.height))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
        
        // settings
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            webView.configuration.ignoresViewportScaleLimits = false
        }
        // user agent
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            if (useCustomUserAgent) {
                webView.customUserAgent = customUserAgent
            }
            if (useUserAgentPostfix) {
                if (useCustomUserAgent) {
                    webView.customUserAgent = customUserAgent + " " + userAgentPostfix
                } else {
                    tempView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
                    tempView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                        if let resultObject = result {
                            self.webView.customUserAgent = (String(describing: resultObject) + " " + userAgentPostfix)
                            self.tempView = nil
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            webView.configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = ""
        }
        
        // bounces
        webView.scrollView.bounces = enableBounceWhenScrolling

        // init observers
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    }
    
    // Initialize UI elements
    // call after WebView has been initialized
    func setupUI() {
        // leftButton.isEnabled = false

        // progress bar
        progressBar = UIProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webViewContainer.frame.width, height: 40))
        progressBar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth]
        progressBar.progress = 0.0
        progressBar.tintColor = progressBarColor
        webView.addSubview(progressBar)
        
        // activity indicator
        activityIndicator.color = activityIndicatorColor
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        // offline container
        offlineIcon.tintColor = offlineIconColor
        offlineButton.tintColor = buttonColor
        offlineView.isHidden = true
        
        // setup navigation bar
        if (forceLargeTitle) {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItem.LargeTitleDisplayMode.always
            }
        }
        if (useLightStatusBarStyle) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        }
        
        // handle menu button changes
        /// set default
        rightButton.title = menuButtonTitle
        /// update if necessary
        updateRightButtonTitle(invert: false)
        /// create callback for device rotation
        let deviceRotationCallback : (Notification) -> Void = { _ in
            // this fires BEFORE the UI is updated, so we check for the opposite orientation,
            // if it's not the initial setup
            self.updateRightButtonTitle(invert: true)
        }
        /// listen for device rotation
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: .main, using: deviceRotationCallback)

        /*
        // @DEBUG: test offline view
        offlineView.isHidden = false
        webViewContainer.isHidden = true
        */
    }

    // load startpage
    func loadAppUrl() {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webAppUrl!)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
    
    // Initialize App and start loading
    func setupApp() {
        setupWebView()
        setupUI()
        loadAppUrl()
    }
    
    // Cleanup
    deinit {
        webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading))
        webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress))
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    // Helper method to determine wide screen width
    func isWideScreen() -> Bool {
        // this considers device orientation too.
        if (UIScreen.main.bounds.width >= wideScreenMinWidth) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    // UI Helper method to update right button text according to available screen width
    func updateRightButtonTitle(invert: Bool) {
        if (changeMenuButtonOnWideScreens) {
            // first, check if device is wide enough to
            if (UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.height < wideScreenMinWidth) {
                // long side of the screen is not long enough, don't need to update
                return
            }
            // second, check if both portrait and landscape would fit
            if (UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.height >= wideScreenMinWidth
                && UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width >= wideScreenMinWidth) {
                // both orientations are considered "wide"
                rightButton.title = alternateRightButtonTitle
                return
            }
            
            // if we land here, check the current screen width.
            // we need to flip it around in some cases though, as our callback is triggered before the UI is updated
            let changeToAlternateTitle = invert
                ? !isWideScreen()
                : isWideScreen()
            if (changeToAlternateTitle) {
                rightButton.title = alternateRightButtonTitle
            } else {
                rightButton.title = menuButtonTitle
            }
        }
    }
}

// WebView Event Listeners
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    // didFinish
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // set title
        if (changeAppTitleToPageTitle) {
            navigationItem.title = webView.title
        }
        // hide progress bar after initial load
        progressBar.isHidden = true
        // hide activity indicator
        activityIndicatorView.isHidden = true
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
    // didFailProvisionalNavigation
    // == we are offline / page not available
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        // show offline screen
        offlineView.isHidden = false
        webViewContainer.isHidden = true
    }
}

// WebView additional handlers
extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
    // handle links opening in new tabs
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
        return nil
    }
    // restrict navigation to target host, open external links in 3rd party apps
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let requestUrl = navigationAction.request.url {
            if let requestHost = requestUrl.host {
                if (requestHost.range(of: allowedOrigin) != nil ) {
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                } else {
                    decisionHandler(.cancel)
                    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(requestUrl)) {
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(requestUrl)
                        } else {
                            // Fallback on earlier versions
                            UIApplication.shared.openURL(requestUrl)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        // Change Navigation style
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = navigationBarColor
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: navigationTitleColor]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = navigationButtonColor
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: navigationTitleColor]
        }

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called Navigation buttons and, If you hide them, Apple will reject your WebView app with the `4.2 minimum functionality`, But either way, to do so- Paste this below `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated) // Hide
}
```

More info  [How to hide a navigation bar from first ViewController in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209453/how-to-hide-a-navigation-bar-from-first-viewcontroller-in-swift)